# ID is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for Table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ms-access-2010

I wanted to delete single data in the database based on their "ID" (Auto Number). But, when i wanted to delete, here is the error that i getting:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll

Additional information: ID is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table."

Here is the code that i am using:

```
private void DeleteDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

            if (_dt.DefaultView.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["ID"]);
                _dt.DefaultView[rowNum].Delete();

                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string query = "DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [ID] = @ID";
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer _sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                    _sounds.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no Data in the Selected Row!", "Error");
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                _sounds.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully!", "Deleted");
            }
        }
```

Here is the database view in the datagridview on my system:

[image]

**Updated:**

Here is the code of view database:

If i didn't include `[ID]` in the `SELECT` query in the `ViewDatabase()`, it will error, but if i include that, and when i click `Print Preview`, it will show the `ID` column as the image below.

```
private void ViewDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter _adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    _ds.Clear();
                    _adapter.Fill(_ds, "Table");
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];

                this.dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

I am aware that if i choose `Product Code` rather than `ID` to delete the data, it will be more possible, but if let's say there are 2 same `Product Code` and when i click delete, both data will be deleted, because it is same `Product Code`.

But, i also wanted to hide the `ID` whenever i click `Print Preview`, i don't want to show any `ID` when i click `Print Preview`. This image below shows the `Print Preview` got `ID` column, where in the view database on the system there is no `ID` visible.

[image]

my question is: 
how do i delete the database using `ID`, but in the `ViewDatabase()` the `ID` column will not be visible to users and whenever i click `Print Preview`, the `ID` will not be visible as well. The `ID` will only be visible to the system (The `ID` on `DeleteDatabase()` will run and the `ID` on `PrintPreview() and ViewDatabase()` will not be visible to users)

i apologize if i am making you confuse.

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>There is no `ID`. You need to delete based on specific data in your table. `ProductCode` looks more reasonable.</strike>

**EDIT**

Based on your update to the question, it appears that there is actually an `ID` column. My guess it is blowing up on this line:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["ID"]);
```

This is probably due to the fact that you limited your `SELECT` query and did not grab `ID`. Which explains your original image of not showing the `ID` column. You can't grab data for a column that you did not include in the `SELECT`.

If you really do not want `ID` to be shown to the user, but still need to delete off of it, then you are going to have to do some leg work and modify the code that displays the `Database Summary`. Basically, you are going to have to modify it to not display specific columns, but also keep track of it. That's more of a design/implementation issue that you'll need to try to resolve on your own first.

Comment: But, if i am using `Product Code` to delete the data, let's say there are 2 same `Product Code`, both datas will be deleted if i click delete, because it is same `Product Code`. I will update my question sir, please refer to it after i updated my question. Thank you very much

Comment: @Kaoru Then you need to add a unique identifier to table. Whether it be a unique string, an identity, int, something, in order to delete just that one row. Or even a composite of keys. Something needs to be unique. You can't just make up something that doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: Thank you very much mr TyCobb, i will consider your answer. I already updated my question. If you don't mind, please refer to it again. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @Kaoru I saw after I posted my reply. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, i made the `ID` column is not visible to the users on the first image is by purpose, and there is no problem right now (Thanks to your solution sir) with the `DeleteDatabase()`, it is working properly. Right now, what i am confuse is how to hide the `ID` column whenever i click `Print Preview` like the second image above. But as you said on your answer, it is more on a design/implementation issue and i will do it on my own first. I will mark your answer as the answer and give a point :)

Once again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have ID column, get the `ProductCode` like below

```
int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

string code = _dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["ProductCode"].ToString();

dt.DefaultView[rowNum].Delete();
```

now you can delete by ProductCode

```
string query = "DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [ProductCode] = @ProductCode";
conn.Open();

using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", code);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: But, if i am using `Product Code` to delete the data, let's say there are 2 same `Product Code`, both datas will be deleted if i click delete, because it is same `Product Code`. I will update my question sir, please refer to it after i updated my question. Thank you very much

Comment: I already updated my question mr Damith and if you don't mind, please refer to it again. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, and my fix doesn't exactly apply to this question, but it applies to the same error. I just wanted to post my fix here for anyone else who might have the same problem. Here's what I had before, and it was throwing the same error:

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="uppeASSET_DESC" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Asset Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" UniqueName="ASSET_DESC" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <telerik:RadLabel ID="lblASSET_DESC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ASSET_DESC") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

The error came because of the `DataField="uppeASSET_DESC"` field in the `telerik:GridTemplateColumn` tag. I didn't realize that this was a databind (I thought it was some kind of name I guess), so my grid was looking in my stored procedure for the column `uppeASSET_DESC` and it didn't find it, so it threw an error. I removed it, and it worked after that. Here's the working version:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Asset Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" UniqueName="ASSET_DESC" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <telerik:RadLabel ID="lblASSET_DESC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ASSET_DESC") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```